# curl to fetch with digest flag

Tags: javascript, curl

There has been other questions on the subject, but nothing seems working for me.
I have a functional CURL, but I want to translate to JS (with Node).

### CURL

```
curl --user "uername:pass" --digest \
 --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
 --include \
 --request POST "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups/MY_GROUP/clusters/MY_CLUSTER/fts/indexes?pretty=true" \
 --data '{
     "collectionName": "collname",
     "database": "myDB",
     "mappings": {
       "dynamic": true
     },
     "name": "default"
   }'
```

### Response

> HTTP/2 401  www-authenticate: Digest realm="MMS Public API",
> domain="", nonce="OtwBmcu89QuyVMLW6FP1W/ZjD3preQl0", algorithm=MD5,
> qop="auth", stale=false content-type: application/json content-length:
> 106 x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 2 date: Wed, 16 Feb 2022 17:05:37
> GMT server: envoy
>
> HTTP/2 200  date: Wed, 16 Feb 2022 17:05:37 GMT
> strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;
> referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
> x-permitted-cross-domain-policies: none x-content-type-options:
> nosniff x-mongodb-service-version:
> gitHash=8284a4ea05955cb13c38df5489a3794b9a691d4f;
> versionString=v20220216 content-type: application/json
> x-frame-options: DENY content-length: 216
> x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 154 server: envoy

I'm not sure why there is a 401 and a 200, but it works. However I get a 401 without the `--digest` flag, and none of the solutions below seems to include the digest?

Below are all the ways I tried, which all return 401 "You are not authorized for this resource.":

### Fetch

```
fetch(url,
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization:
        'Basic ' +
        Buffer.from(
          'user:pass'
        ).toString('base64'),
    },
    body: dataString,
  }
)
```

Same result with

### Request

```
const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};

var options = {
  url: url,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers,
  body: dataString,
  auth: {
    user: 'user',
    pass: 'pass',
  },
};

request(options, (error: any, response: any, body: any) => {
    ...
});
```

### node-libcurl

```
  const curl = new Curl();
  curl.setOpt(Curl.option.HTTPHEADER, [
    'Content-Type: application/json',
  ]);
  curl.setOpt(Curl.option.URL, url);
  curl.setOpt(Curl.option.POST, true);
  curl.setOpt(Curl.option.USERPWD, 'user:pass');
  curl.setOpt(Curl.option.POSTFIELDS, dataString);
```

Even

### PHP

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "...");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:pass');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

**Edit for the package `request-digest`**

```
digestRequest
  .requestAsync({
    host: url,
    path: urlPath,
    port: 80,
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: body,
  })
  .then(function (response: any) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error: any) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

### Response

> Error: Bad request, answer is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PHP

You need to specify that it's a digest:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
```

## Node Fetch

This is what I have found [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/node-fetch+digest+auth):

```
fetch(url, {
    ... 
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(`${username}:${password}`, 'binary').toString('base64')
    }
    ...
})
```

Comparing your code with the proposed code above I see that `, 'binary'` is missing from yours.

## request-digest

There is a [request-digest](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-digest) package that may help you. Examples (taken from the link shared in this paragraph):

### Callback

```
var digestRequest = require('request-digest')('username', 'password');
digestRequest.request({
  host: 'http://test.com',
  path: '/api/v1/test.json',
  port: 80,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    'Custom-Header': 'OneValue',
    'Other-Custom-Header': 'OtherValue'
  }
}, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
 
  console.log(body);
});
```

### Promise-only

```
var digestRequest = require('request-digest')('username', 'password');
digestRequest.requestAsync({
  host: 'http://test.com',
  path: '/api/v1/test.json',
  port: 80,
  method: 'GET',
  excludePort: false,
  headers: {
    'Custom-Header': 'OneValue',
    'Other-Custom-Header': 'OtherValue'
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.body);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error.statusCode);
  console.log(error.body);
});
```

Comment: I already tried that for PHP, no luck on that side. I edited my question to include request-digest, I get a strange error.

Comment: @Shadoweb first question: what is the HTTP status in the case of request-digest? Second question: how did you structure `dataString`? Is it possible that it should be a JSON? Or a stringified JSON? I would test with both.

Comment: I put the `json: true,` so it accepts JSON format, I also tried to strigify it without success.
But anyway I found a solution with `exec()` and it works.

Comment: It accepts JSON format, yes, I was wondering how the variable you pass was defined. If you have a solution already which solves the problem, then never mind, I'm glad it was resolved!